# findBy Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine

Gostaria de tirar uma duvida, estou utilizando o comando para fazer um filtro:

```
$FinContaspagar = $em->getRepository(FinContaspagar::class)->findBy(array('grupo' => '0'));
```

Porém, eu gostaria que a condição de dentro do array fosse **grupo** diferente de 0 (**zero**). Eu testei alguns operadores de comparação do PHP para atender minha condição (**!=**, **<>**), porém não deu certo. Não achei nada relativo a isso na documentação.

Será que vou ter que montar Um **DQL** para isso?

Answer (score 3):

**EDITADO**

Cara, nesse caso eu iria de createQueryBuilder.

Ficaria:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()->from(FinContaspagar::class, 'f');

$qb->select('f');

$qb->where($qb->expr()->neq('f.grupo', $grupo));

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Eu disse uma solução mas não disse se é possível. Até onde sei acho que não é possível fazer do jeito que você quer (posso estar errado). Um tempo atrás também busquei por uma solução para resolver esta questão e não encontrei. Então resolvi usar o query builder mesmo. Se encontrar uma solução não exite em compartilhar!

Comment: Fiz o teste que você encaminhou, só adicionei o `->select(f)` e substitui o $grupo por 0 para fim de testes, não me retornou nenhum valor... retornou `SELECT f FROM ModuloFinanceiro\Entities\FinContaspagar f WHERE f.grupo <> 0`. Sendo que existem vários. Será que devo adcionar mais uma condição?

Comment: Verdade, eu copiei de um código meu e esqueci de completar com o que faltava. Mal ai! Só não entendi o que quis dizer com "Sendo que existem vários". Várias condições? Outra coisa, o retorno de `return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();` foi `SELECT f FROM ModuloFinanceiro\Entities\FinContaspagar f WHERE f.grupo <> 0`?

Comment: Aqui deu certo. Se tivesse retornado um erro ai, diria para colocar o 0(zero) entre aspas porque se deixar sem aspas, o banco vai entender que o zero é uma coluna da tabela (pelo menos foi assim aqui).